# How do I delete certain files from a folder that don't the match names from a df column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to delete specific files from a folder.

There are about 400 files in this folder (WAVE files mostly, but a couple text files as well).

I have a dataframe that has a column listing all the files I need to keep. There is no real pattern to how they are named. Here is an example of what it looks like.

```
df<- data.frame(A = c("12947_94", "908908_83","383","map_1","map_2","map_4","testing2.d"))
```

I want to remove every file from this folder that does NOT match the file names from the column in my dataframe.

I successfully removed ALL the files in the folder this way

```
files <- list.files(paste("C:/Users..."))

do.call(unlink,list(list.files("C:/Users...",full.names=T)))
```

but don't know how to modify or adjust this code to only remove files that do not match the names in my dataframe column.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest the user of `%in%` to determine if an existing file is in your "keep list" (`df$A`).

Comment: Does the dataframe really contain the file names? Do you have a file named "12947_94" or is it more like "12947_94.wav" or "12947_94.txt"?

Comment: list.files is a vectorized function already, so you can pass the vector of directories with selection pattern to it

Comment: @r2evans can you explain the context of how that would fit? Is it within the list.files part of the code?

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre that's a good point. I realize that when I list the files it includes .wav so I suppose the file technically must be "12947_94.wav"

Comment: But is the .wav in the dataframe vector? That will change the answer I give.

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre Ahh no, it is not in the dataframe vector itself.

Comment: @cebola: `files[ ! files %in% df$A ]` gives you a vector of files' names that are not in your keep-list.

Comment: @r2evans thank you. I think only issue there (apologies this wasn't clear in the question) was that the files technically have either a .wav or .txt extension but unfortunately my file names in the dataframe do not.

Comment: I see now the need for `grep` and friends. Sorry I missed it in my first pass through the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to keep the file names to retain in a dataframe rather than a vector. Let's assume your file names are correct and also `C:/Users...` means you substituted it but it exists. One way to do this would be:

```
files.in.dir <- list.files(paste("C:/Users..."), full.names = T)
files.to.keep <- c("12947_94", "908908_83","383","map_1","map_2","map_4","testing2.d")
files.to.remove <- list(files.in.dir[!(files.in.dir %in% grep(paste(files.to.keep,collapse = "|"), files.in.dir, value=TRUE))])
do.call(unlink, files.to.remove)
```

I have used these 4 steps for brevity. `grep(paste(files.to.keep,collapse = "|")` means creating a pattern which matches any of the files in `files.to.keep` list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer, it almost worked perfectly. All I needed to do was make "files.to.remove" a list and it ran. The only other issue I ran into was that it didn't remove files that included the full file name even if it wasn't an exact match. Example: 17083_02 was in "files.to.keep" but it also kept 17083_02(02) even though 17083_02(02) wasn't included in "files.to.keep." Is there any way to make this remove files while matching the name? There weren't many so it was easy to do by hand, just curious. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice, glad that I was able to help. I am also learning R at the moment, so it was kind a good exercise for me too. Good point, I have wrapped files.to.remove in a list(). The reason that 17083_02(02) was kept is the regex which is passed into `grep` function doesn't do exact match, it's lazy. Let me see how I could improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. If there are files with more than one period in them in df$A, I don't know how well it will perform.

```
df<- data.frame(A = c("12947_94", "908908_83","383","map_1","map_2","map_4","testing2.d"))
files <- c("12947_94.wav", "908908_83.txt", "383.txt", "map_1.bmp", "map_2.bmp", "map_4.pdf", "testing2.d.wmf", 'map5.png')

short_files <- gsub('\\.([^:]+)$', '', files)
drop_files <- files[!short_files %in% gsub('\\.([^:]+)$', '', df$A)]

unlink(file.path('C:/users', drop_files))
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for taking the time to help. Unfortunately it didn't run. The "drop_files" part included every file within the folder and didn't subtract the ones from my dataframe. I ran the unlink part as well for kicks and that didn't drop anything from the actual folder. Hopefully I wasn't missing any information in my question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought it worked on my computer, but may not have tested it enough. The answer above looks better anyways